# Extract child objects into array inside MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

In my collection, all of my documents have an array called `tags`:

```
"tags" : [
        {
            "name" : "a", 
            "weight" : NumberInt(32)
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "b", 
            "weight" : NumberInt(26)
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "c", 
            "weight" : NumberInt(25)
        }, 
        ...
]
```

Each object in the array has keys `name` and `weight`. I need to remove the `weight` key, so that I'm just left with the `names` in an single-level array like `["a", "b", "c"...]`

---

An explanation of why I need to do this:

Inside my aggregation, I want to calculate the number of matches between an array `x = ["a", "b", "d"]` and whatever tags each document has.

This is as far as I've gotten- inside a `$project` I create a new variable like so:

```
"$project": {
    ...
    "diff": {
       "$size": {
          "$setIntersection": [ x, "$tags" } ]
       }
    },
    ...
}
```

But of course this doesn't work as the `$tags` array is full of objects, and not strings. I need to strip the `weight` from the tags array and leave it just as an array of `names` like `["a", "b", "c" ...]`, then it should work.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `. dot` notation with the `name` inside `tags`. Something like

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "matches": {
      "$size": {
        "$setIntersection": [
          [ "a", "b", "d"],
          "$tags.name"
        ]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. I didn't expect it to be so simple